# Trouble rendering a page in Express.js after successful DELETE request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

### I am using Node.js , MongoDB and ejs to build a simple URL shortening project but I faced a problem where I'm unable to render a page after successfully handling a DELETE request. The 'deletion' page is being loaded in the response preview in the browser's network tab, but it's not being displayed in the main window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB47O.png)

```
const express = require('express');
const Url = require('./models/url');

...

app.route('/url/:id').delete(async(req , res) => {
    const shortId = req.params.id;
    await Url.findOneAndDelete({
        shortId
    })
    res.status(200);
    return res.render('deletion' , {
        id: shortId,
    })
})

...
```

This is my ejs code

```
...

<body>
    <h1>Short URL Created!!</h1>
    
    ...

    <button onclick="deletefunction('<%= url.shortUrl %>')">Delete URL</button>    
    <script>
        async function deletefunction(url){
            await fetch(`/url/${url}` , {
                method: 'DELETE'
            })
            } 
    </script>
</body>
```

I expected that that clicking this button would delete URL from database and render another HTMl page. But instead nothing happened on the frontend page , the URL did got deleted from the database but it did not loaded the HTML page I was expecting.

I tried removing `res.render()` to `res.json()`. The same this happened that nothing loaded on the page but the json was returned correctly when checked in networks tab.

Comment: Your code fetches the endpoint but does nothing with the retrieved page. You probably want the DELETE endpoint to return JSON instead of text/html, and then use that JSON data after the fetch call to dynamically update the page contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to update your routes to send a redirect signal than handle the signal in your ejs view script tag.

```
app.route('/url/:id').delete(async (req, res) => {
    const shortId = req.params.id;
    await Url.findOneAndDelete({ shortId });
    res.status(200).send({ redirect: '/deletion-page' }); // Send redirect signal
});
```

Then for your EJS you would have the signal replace your body tag with whatever you want for your delete page

```
 ...

<body>
    <h1>Short URL Created!!</h1>
    
      ...

    <button onclick="deletefunction('<%= url.shortUrl %>')">Delete URL</button>

    <script>
        async function deletefunction(url) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`/url/${url}`, {
                    method: 'DELETE'
                });
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Deletion failed');
                }
                const html = await response.text();
                document.body.innerHTML = html; // Replace your current body with the new HTML for your page
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('An error occurred:', error);
                // You could also update the page to show the error by rendering a new 404 ejs page this is recommended for a friendly UI with a redirect to home page button
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```